# After Ending Task Scheduler Task Python.exe does not close

Tags: python, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I have a task scheduler task which calls a bat file. I run the task using task scheduler and everything works smoothly, no error etc. But when it comes to ending the task "python.exe" keeps running in the background.

My bat file is just a single line code:

`.env\Scripts\python run.py --config_file=config\my_config.ini`

I have like 8 products running at the same time. When I want to stop one of the tasks to make changes, I have to end all of them using task scheduler and then kill the python processes from task manager one by one (Because I don't know which python.exe belongs to which task). After that I can restart the remaining 7 tasks from task scheduler again.

This problem occurs in the server we use to run our products. I have tried creating the same task in my local. With same .bat file and python program it actually stops python.exe unlike the server. What could be the problem that i am missing? My local has "Windows 10". The server causes the problem has "Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter"

**Edit**: Instead of calling the bat file from Task Scheduler, I have tried calling the script with arguments, It worked somehow. Even though this saves the day, it is very limiting. And I am still searching the proper solution.

[image: Temporary Fix calling the script from Task Scheduler]